# Summations of values and showing result in the same row in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using iReport designer. I have four columns in report. Value of one column will be calculated by doing sum summation and subtraction of other columns.

My result formula looks like this :

```
($V{cust_amount} == null ? new BigDecimal(0) : $V{cust_amount}).subtract( ($V{airlines_amount} == null ? new BigDecimal(0) : $V{airlines_amount}).subtract(($V{indi_amount} == null ? new BigDecimal(0) : $V{indi_amount}) ) )
```

But the result is coming just at the next row of the expected one. I am attaching a picture also.

[image]

Here the amount -15100 should come one the first row. But every value is coming just below the right row and first row is always null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ternary expression seems fine - the problem is with value assignment to the variables you are using. The values are assigned after the first row is evaluated and either never change or they are assigned the same values over and over again.

You may fix value assignment to the variables but I recommend ditching the variables and using actual fields in the expression like this $F{cust_amount} - then you will be guaranteed proper value assignment before the row is printed.

Comment: Thanks. If I use actual field expressions, it's giving the proper values in all rows. But in bottom row the is a summation row which sums up the amounts based on  a group. It's not giving the actual value. It's not adding the last row.
I have already created a variable and it's reset type is set at that group, calculation is Sum and variable expression is given actual fields in the expression.

You can take a look here.
http://s17.postimg.org/nnqj711vj/irpeort.png

Comment: In this case you will have to use an extra variable to hold the value of your ternary expression (let's call it rowTotal). The Total under MARKUP must be evaluated as +=rowTotal and reset on group.

Comment: Pardon me for my ignorance. I am holding the value of ternary expression in a variable. But I am not getting the text field expression. Like this :
`$V{rowTotal}.add( $V{rowTotal} )`
Note that I am using BigDecimal datatype. And it's evaluation time is set at Group.

Comment: You do not need to specify the summation expression - Jasper will do that for you. Simply set Calculation=Sum, ResetType=Group, VariableExpression=$V{rowTotal} - which means the sum of all rowTotals within this group.

Comment: It still not adding the last row of the group. It's always adding the last row in the calculation at next evaluation. And always ignoring the last row. You can take a look here. http://s27.postimg.org/xy4pppy9v/markup_total.png
You can see it's adding the last row of the first evaluation **-5000** at the second group evaluation calculation and ignoring the last row of second group.

Comment: You must have missed something - it works perfectly for me. Here is a sample report I made just now using the iReport sample database so you can test drive it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5RlXDFsoD4pQTNFOFJOS0prQ1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But it's not working in same way. Do you know any process that will print the value of the next row ? like it will print the 2nd row's value on the first row, 3rd row's value of 2nd row and onwards.

Comment: I do not think that can be done with general Jasper features - once a row is evaluated it is history. But you surely can do that with a custom Java data source.